# Angular datatables, can't click on row buttons when row click event is configured

Tags: javascript, angular, datatables

I am using the angular datatables module in my project and i configured a function using the `rowrollback` function to perform actions when clicked on the row. but when using that i can't click on buttons in my row, like actions designed for each row (e.g delete modify client ).

I tried not to add the Actions column in my `dtconfig` object but it made my datatable not get triggered.

here is my code :

**dtOptions :**

```
dtOptions = {
            pagingType: 'full_numbers',
            pageLength: 10,
            columns: [{
                title: 'Current Owner',
                data: 'CurrentOwner'
            },{
                title: 'Doc Hash',
                data: 'hash'
            },{
                title: 'Doc Name',
                data: 'name'
            },{
                title: 'Doc Owner',
                data: 'DocumentOwner'
            },{
                title: 'Time Stamp',
                data: 'Timestamp'
            },{
                title: 'Actions',
                data: 'actions'
            }],
            rowCallback: (row: Node, data: Object |any[] , index: number) => {

                try{
                    const self = this;
                    // Unbind first in order to avoid any duplicate handler
                    // (see https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/87)
                    $('td', row).unbind('click');
                    $('td', row).bind('click', () => {
                        let X ={};
                        Object.assign(X,data);
                        console.log(X)
                        console.log(this.Certificates[index]);
                        self.DetailedCertificate=this.Certificates[index];
                        $(this.detailRef.nativeElement);
                        $(this.detailRef.nativeElement).modal("show");
                    });
                    return row;
                }
                catch (e){
                    console.error("error"+e);
                }
            }
```

**HTML Table :**

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of dataRows" class=".row" >
                  <td style="text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow-wrap: break-word">{{row.CO}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.KC}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.DocName}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.DocOwner}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.TimeStamp}}</td>
                  <td class="text-right">
                    <button   class="btn btn-lg btn-simple btn-info btn-icon" (click)="CO(row.KC,row.DocOwner)"><i class="material-icons">person_pin_circle</i></button>
                    <button  class="btn btn-lg btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon" (click)="RC(row.KC,row.DocOwner)"><i class="material-icons">close</i></button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a table in angular that accomplishes what you want.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  dataRows: any[] = [
    { kc: 'kc1', docName: 'Document 1', docOwner: 'Johnny', timeStamp: 'last week'},
    { kc: 'kc2', docName: 'Document 2', docOwner: 'Jacob', timeStamp: 'yesterday'},
    { kc: 'kc3', docName: 'Document 3', docOwner: 'Jingleheimer', timeStamp: 'today'},
    { kc: 'kc4', docName: 'Document 4', docOwner: 'Schmidt', timeStamp: 'tomorrow'}
  ];

  buttonInRowClick(event: any): void {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Button in the row clicked.');
  }

  wholeRowClick(): void {
    console.log('Whole row clicked.');
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>KC</th>
    <th>Doc Name</th>
    <th>Doc Owner</th>
    <th>Time Stamp</th>
    <th>Button</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of dataRows" (click)="wholeRowClick()">
    <td>{{row.kc}}</td>
    <td>{{row.docName}}</td>
    <td>{{row.docOwner}}</td>
    <td>{{row.timeStamp}}</td>
    <td><button (click)="buttonInRowClick($event)">do thing</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This line adds the function call to every row that ngFor generates.

`<tr *ngFor="let row of dataRows" (click)="myFunction()">...</tr>`

The key to making sure the click events on buttons within the rows don't interfere with the overall row click is to add
    event.stopPropagation();

in the functions that the nested buttons call.

Comment: What you mentioned is making the clicking on the row not trigger the click on the button inside that row. what i want to do is click the button not the row.

Comment: The code I posted allows you to: 1) trigger a function for a row click. 2) trigger a function on a button click within the row (like edit, delete, etc.) without firing the overall row function. I have edited my answer to clarify what I meant.

Comment: i am sorry to say that it didn't work, even removing the `click` event from the row doesn't work. the buttons fire nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the CO() function by using jquery call in AfterViewInit interface like below. And get 'row.KC' value by setting it as id in html

```
 ngAfterViewInit(){
    var _thisDoc = this;
    $('#user-table').on('click', '.btn-circle', function(){
      _thisDoc.CO(this.id);
    });
  }

  CO(e) {
    console.log(e); //row.KC value
  }
```